# How to resolve this "cast to pointer from type of different size" warning?

Tags: c++, qt, casting, reference, qdbus

I have two programs that communicate over the D-Bus. In one of the there is a function that takes two parameters namely `const char* data` and `int size` and in another one I have a function that returns a value of the type `unsigned char`. I place a function call in the first program like this `function((char*)program2->function().value(), 1)` but i get the warning **cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]**. how should i resolve this warning? also I'm using Qt libraries.

EDIT:

actually in the function that takes the `const char*` and `int` I append the data to a `QByteArray` which accepts `const char*` and a size of type `int` in it's constructor as provided by Qt and the other program is supposed to return a number in the range 0-255 hence the `unsinged char`. If what I'm doing is wrong what's the best way to obtain the desired result?

Also call to program2->function invokes the following:

```
inline QDBusPendingReply<uchar> type()
    {
        QList<QVariant> argumentList;
        return asyncCallWithArgumentList(QLatin1String("type"), argumentList);
    }
```

this class has a function called value() which invokes:

```
inline typename Select<0>::Type value() const
    {
        return argumentAt<0>();
    }
```

**NOTE:** my main purpose of this question was to find out a way to create a reference to the returned result of calling a function defined within the proxy class not how to convert it to something acceptable for creation of a `QByteArray` so please stop adding unrelated tags like `QByteArray` or `QtCore` etc.

Comment: The warning seems fairly clear; an `int` is not the same type as a `char *`, so the conversion you're doing won't make any sense.

Comment: @Oli: It seems to be the `unsigned char` and `unsigned char*` having different size.  The actual argument of `1` for the `int` parameter is working just fine.

Comment: Why not just `auto const p = program2->function();` then just `(&p, 1)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the address of the data... which would look like

```
function2(& program2->function().value(), 1);
```

and would be perfectly safe, since the lifetime of the temporary variable is until the end of the complete expression, which is long enough<sup>1</sup> for `function2` to use it.

Unfortunately, you can't use the `&` address-of operator on an rvalue.  But there is a workaround, since you can bind a `const` lvalue reference to an rvalue, and you want a pointer to `const` data anyway:

```
template<T>
const T* get_addr(const T& v) { return &v; }

function2( get_addr(program2->function().value()), 1 );
```

If you get a signed-vs-unsigned, mismatch, try

```
function2( get_addr<char>(program2->function().value()), 1 );
```

Of course this is a lot of work just to avoid giving the variable a name, as [Captain Obvlious has done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23418158/103167).

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless `function2` saves that pointer for later, but if it does then you shouldn't be using a local variable to hold the value either, but pay very close attention to object lifetime.

Comment: please have a look at class `QDBusPendingReply` and review your answer. also check my question description update

Comment: @MoKi: So `program2->function()` in your question is this `someobj->type()->value()`?  Nothing in my answer changes.  Only if `function2` stores a copy of the pointer would there be any problem.

Comment: @laszlo: changing, no definitely not. Adding another overload of function2 that accepts a single byte, perhaps.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Do you really think this is the only call in the entire program to his `function2`?  I guess if that's true, your suggestion would make sense.  But it seems unlikely.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Where's the change to `const char&`?  The only place I suggested that was in a templated helper function, that has `const T&`.  The `function2` retains it's `read()`-like signature of `const char*, size_t`

Comment: @LaszloPapp: So.... this function you have such a dislike for is so bad that a version got standardized as `std::address_of` ... Why are you recommending that a C++ program not be written in C++, just because Qt is one of the dependencies?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: My answer was given to a question tagged `c++`, with Qt mentioned as an afterthought.  Clearly MoKi was looking for the C++ way of doing it.  I see no reason to change my answer in response to the change in question, since it still will work just fine.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I did mention the downsides in my answer. "this is a lot of work just to avoid giving the variable a name"

Answer (score 1):

I do not think what you are doing is safe, hence your code might not work at all. If your function() is returning an "unsigned char", its going to make a copy of it and return it. At the same time your other function() is taking a "const char*". I suggest to modify your program2->function() to return a "char *".

Comment: This sounds like a recipe for dangling pointer.  Where is the first function going to store its result, that will still be valid when the second function runs?

Comment: This is probably the strangest idea. Why would you do that for a simple char which is then later converted QByteArray?

Answer (score 0):

Converting an integer to a pointer is not a really good idea especially if you don't know why the conversion is necessary and what exactly it does. It looks like the conversion isn't even necessary and you really need a solution to properly call the function instead of fixing the cast warning. From the code and description you provided it appears you want to send a single byte returned by the call to `program2->function()`. Since the value returned by this function is an rvalue you can't directly take it's address. Instead you can to store it in a variable and then pass a pointer to that instead. Something like the code below should let you do what you want.

```
char value = program2->function();
function(&value, 1);
```

Comment: please check my updated question description. The call `program2->function()` returns a `QDBusPendingReply` object.